# Measuring qubit as the presence or absence of a particle

Tags: quantum-information

My background is not physics so forgive the confusion.

If we use photon polarization as qubits, I can understand that the angle is in a superposition between 0 and 90 degrees.

But we can also use the presence or absence of the photon itself as the two orthogonal states of a qubit. What sense does it make for that qubit to be in a superposition?

Comment: This can and has been suggested in theory, but both single photon generation and single photon detection are plagued by large experimental errors. At the current state of experimental art using spatial information about single photons is, IMHO, a losing proposition, at least from a practical angle. If you look at the plethora of multi-path interferometer experiments, that's kind of what they are doing... with truly horrible experimental errors.

Comment: What does *"What sense does it make for that qubit"* even mean? The qubit does not have a feeling of sense.

Comment: Note that encoding information in presence/absense of particles causes problems due to superselection rules (e.g., superpositions of particles typically cannot be created).  This is not true for photons, but a similar problem might arise due to the lack of a phase reference. There are quite a few things which can be said about quantum information in the presence of superselection rules.